# How to delay so that LED stays on a bit longer?

Tags: arduino-uno, johnny-five

I have a circuit with a shift register which controls 8 LEDs: http://node-ardx.org/exercises/5. In code, I created a function `cycle()` cycle through each LED one at a time, but this occurs too quickly on the board. How can I add a delay inside the loop so that each LED stays on for 500ms?

Here's my code:

```
var five = require("johnny-five"), board, shiftRegister;

board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {
  shiftRegister = new five.ShiftRegister({
    pins: {
      data: 2,
      clock: 3,
      latch: 4
    }
  });

  var bytes = [
    00000001,
    00000010,
    00000100,
    00001000,
    00010000,
    00100000,
    01000000,
    10000000,
    00000000
  ];

  function cycle() {
      for ( var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ ) {
          console.log(bytes[i]);
          shiftRegister.send(bytes[i]);
      }
    }

  this.repl.inject({
    sr: shiftRegister
  });

  cycle();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is already provided in the article.

```
  var i = 0; 
  function cycle() {
    console.log(bytes[i]);
    sr.send(bits[i]);
    i++;
    if( i<bytes.length )
      setTimeout(cycle, 300);
  }
```

Comment: I don't want the cycle function to repeat. I do want to delay just after sending the new byte to the register just after changing the LEDs.

Comment: See edit above. It now only does one cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a delay of 500ms?

```
function cycle() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ ) {
        console.log(bytes[i]);
        sr.send(bits[i]);
        delay(500);
    }
  }
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a function called "delay".

Comment: Good job that's not the language we're discussing then!

Comment: Which variant of C or C++ is the "var" keyword supported in?

Comment: In that case you'll want [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript) I imagine.

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I run the changes above, the REPL reports `delay is not defined`. I'm running Johnny Five v0.8.32. Where is delay defined by Johnny Five?